# Ubuntu Server 15.10 installing CUDA drivers

Tags: cuda

I was just wonder in how I would go about installing CUDA on my Ubuntu Server machine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

please review the [CUDA Download Zone](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Currently the latest version of Ubuntu officially supported is Ubuntu 15.04. So of course it might work to install the drivers on Ubuntu 15.10, but I haven't done it yet.

Please see [this guide](https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Installation_with_CUDA_on_Ubuntu_server_1104) on how to install CUDA on Ubuntu Server 11.04. Be sure to take care with the gcc steps the guide does. Before simply copy&paste the commands, please check that it won't change things you don't want to change.

[This guide](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/10/25/cuda-6-dot-5-on-aws-gpu-instance-running-ubuntu-14-dot-04/) gives help on how to install CUDA 6.5 on an Amazon AWS instance of Ubuntu server. You might adopt the steps and see if it works.

Good luck,
Simon